# Same app in both version in one device

Tags: java, android

I have one chat app. One is published on play store and another is my Android Studio project for this app, which is updated after the published. Now how can I test the updated without publish again on play store? Should I first uninstall the play store app from my phone and after run the project from my Android Studio?
Here is my app link:https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jimmytrivedi.lapitchat

Comment: you can change the package name and debug it on your phone

Comment: What if I'll simply run the app? Will it not changes? I think it should.

Comment: @RuchikaSingh how about setting up the alpha nd beta testing on your app in playstore ? https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Comment: Can you test my app and suggest me for some improvements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create productFlavours in your `build.gradle`

```
   productFlavors {
    dev {
        applicationId "com.example.demo.dev"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    production {
        applicationId "com.example.demo"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}
```

select build varient to run app with specific flavour

[Configure build variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants)

Comment: I don't think it is necessary. Because when I uninstall the play store version and and run from the Android Studio, it works fine with updated changes.

Comment: with this, you can have both `play store` and your `dev version` on a device no need to uninstall/install particular version

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use a different application ID for the release and debug versions of your app. You can do this with a simple:

```
debug {
    applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
}
```

In the gradle script of your app module. In this way you don't even need to repeat the common part of the package name. If you want to test the release version while developing, you can do the same thing in a specific app flavor.

In this case, I also suggest you to change the app name and / or icon for the debug builds, to be able to easily recognise the version once installed. You can do this overriding the main resources in the debug folder.